# Express - next() is not calling in controller

Tags: express, mean-stack, mean

In my MEAN stack application, I've 2 collections - News & Comment. When a comment is posted, it will be saved first and then it will update News collection. 
 
I'm using 2 functions with the help of express as below:

```
//CommentsController.js
//Function  1
exports.addComment = (req, res, next) => {
  const comment = new Comment({
    //Key values
  });
  comment
    .save()
    .then(createdComment => {
      req.createdComment = comment;
      next();
    })
};


//Function 2
exports.updateNews = (req, res, next) => {
  let newsId = req.body.newsId;
  let comment = req.createdComment;
  News.findById(newsId)
    .then(news => {
      News.update({ _id: newsId }, {
        $push: { comment }
      })
      .then(item => {
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "Comment added successfully"
        });
      })
    });
}
```

My router file is as below:

```
const express = require("express");
var CommentsController = require('../controllers/commentsController');

const router = express.Router();
router.post("", CommentsController.addComment);
module.exports = router;
```

The problem I'm facing is that, after addComment successfully saved, it's not calling "updateNews" function even when next() is being called. I'm not sure about what is missing.

Comment: Why would it? What connects the two functions together? Seems like you're not including everything necessary for people to be able to help.

Comment: @DaveNewton, with Express we don't have to connect them. next() is sufficient

Comment: How would it know what's next? (And I'd argue from the evidence that "next()" is *not* sufficient, since it doesn't work.)

Comment: Post your router/middleware

Comment: Did you register `updateNews` as the next middleware in the router?

Comment: I updated my description with router details.

Comment: Function in controller and route different ?

Answer (score 0):

AS mentioned by @vapurrmaid (in the comments), I found the answer to my own question.

The answer is:

```
router.post("", CommentsController.addComment, CommentsController.updateNews);
```

Thanks @vapurrmaid

Comment: `addCommentToNews` should be `addComment` according to your question

Comment: ... Roughly what I said, including the other comment stating you didn't provide enough information to help--but at least you listened to *someone*.

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr, Thanks.